# Test automation chromedrive not working on github

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, cucumber, github-actions

I m creating a simple test automation project using java selenium webdrive with cucumber
My project is working fine on local machine

But i don't know how to run it on github exactly

1- i create a repo on git

2- i find a yml file showing how to run the action on git

I try it but it fail on getting the chromedrive file
[image]
[[image: enter image description here][1]]
[image: error]
Any help

Comment: Did you check which operating system you are running the GitHub action on? `.exe` files can't run on a Unix system.

Comment: It's also good practice to include the actual text of any errors and code. It's easier to read then a screenshot. You can use markdown to format it.